# How to access data in a partial view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble how to architect a nav menu depends on data from a model.

I started by setting up a controller for my static pages.

```
# Static content

class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def contact
  end

  def services
  end
end
```

Then I created some partials and then setup my application.html.erb to display them on every page.

```
<body>
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<%= render "shared/header" %>
<%= render "shared/nav" %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render "shared/footer" %>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I need to create a nav menu where the client can change the links, so I have a model that stories the name and slug of the menu item.

So now in my shared/_nav.html.erb I need access to a @menus object.  What's the rails best practices for setting something like that up? Coming from other MVC architectures, my first idea was to link a controller to the nav partial, but I don't see a way to do that in rails. Is there a way I can make my @menus object globally accessible in the whole app, since I will need it for every page?

Answer (score 1):

The most common used practice is to access to class variables in actions views, and pass class or an other variables to partial view as local variables:

So if `nav` is a common used partials in your case, pass local `@menus` as local variable to the subview:

```
<%= render "shared/nav", menus: @menus %>
```

The access in `nav` to `menus` not a `@menus`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a non-AR ruby class that has all the resources you need in initialize it with a callback in your controller, or initialize it in a variable in a helper module so that it's available when you need it.